# Aws Glue Referenced file path in Python shell not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

AWS Glue PythonShell ETL - Trying to Connecting to Api using configuration file (config_file.json) which is specified in the Referenced File Path Configuration.

[image]

Accessing Via :

`'config_file.json'` in the code.

**Error : Cannot find the file config_file.json**

How to provide the path for referenced files in AWS Glue Pythonshell ETL Job?

Comment: Maybe use boto3 to create an s3 client in your code and then assign that config location programmatically